Reflection on PCB + antenna
I have a transducer with 64 outputs. I want to have 3 of the outputs on my amplifier input in a way that I can choose between them. My first idea for implementing this was to use jumpers as follows:

Antenna formation that can cause reflection:


I can choose to have the 3 different inputs by having the jumper on different pins, but my concern is that this solution can cause reflection and can pick up noise for the amplifier input (the input signal is current in range of 50-150 μA @ 3.5 MHz).
Please let me know if you have a suggestion to implement this without any risk of noise and reflection.
EDIT following answer: Using dip switch:
https://www.digikey.be/nl/products/detail/cts-electrocomponents/218-4LPSTJR/5223844

Position of the micro switches in the circuit:


What's the transducer and what bandwidth signal does it produce?

@Andy aka Hello Andy, it is an ultrasound transducer and the bandwidth would be 7 MHz.

This is a very low frequency, so not very sensitive at all. The general rule of thumb is to never place any stubs or "mini antennas" anywhere in the RF path though. Header strips being cute little antenna arrays - there are probably few less suitable components out there. Is 0 ohm resistors an option, instead of jumpers?

Jumpers don't have to be on/off - you can have three rows of pins where one row goes to/through some suitable impedance to ground.


it is an ultrasound transducer and the bandwidth would be 7 MHz

Let me begin by saying that all tracks and wires form an antenna to some extent so when you say this: -

Antenna formation that can cause reflection

This is always possibly but, we have rules of thumb that guide us. The most well-used rule of thumb is that the wavelength of a signal must be at least ten times greater than the length of an anomalous interface (your jumper). This generally applies to transmission lines where we use the rule of thumb to determine if we should have a termination resistor to prevent reflections.
So, the wavelength of 7 MHz in free space is: -
$$\lambda=\dfrac{V_P}{f}$$

\$V_P\$ is the velocity of propagation in free space (also the speed of light)
\$f\$ is the upper frequency limit of our signal

In your scenario, \$\lambda\$ turns out to be about 42.8 metres. However, on a circuit board where the velocity of propagation is around two thirds of \$c\$, we should use 28.6 metres.
Given that your circuit anomaly is only maybe around a centimetre in length we meet the rule of thumb by a country mile.

my concern is that this solution can cause reflection and can pick up
noise for the amplifier input

Just how sensitive your input might be is an unknown factor. What cross talk might occur between the three tracks coming from the ultrasound transducer is also an unknown factor.

@ Andy aka thank you very much Andy, would you please let me know if there is other options like micro switches to be replaced by the jumper idea?

I'm sure there are plenty of options in that area and, they would be lower profile. I'm thinking of those little DIP switches you see on circuit boards @Andromeda

Hello Andy, based on your suggestion I could find an suitable dip switch. I added the picture to this post, would you please let me know should I follow an specific measure for routing from the transducer to the dip switch? Considering this tracks can add capacitance and inductance to my input signal to the amplifier. I will have 10 different amplifiers on different place on the PCB, so I would have different lengths as well, possibly very long track like 15 CM.

Andy I specifically mean the thickness of the track from transducer to the dip switch.

You'll need to link to the data sheet of the transducer @Andromeda

@ Andy aka the transducer is a custom-made ultrasound transducer ,which has been made in our research group, so there is no datasheet for that. The transducer in fact can be modeled as a current source in parallel with an capacitor and resistor. With the following details: Input capacitance: 1nF, resistance: 1K, current output 50-150 uA, frequency 3.5 MHz.

I would put ground traces between each of the three signal traces to prevent cross-talk being a problem. Other than that and, because the custom device is unknown to me that's all I (or probably anyone) can offer @Andromeda

@Andromeda Those data would be important context to add to several of your recent op-amp questions. When commenters ask about connected elements, this is precisely what information they find most helpful.

@TimWilliams I would discourage adding stuff to previously raised questions because it just potentially invalidates all previous answers.

@ Andy aka Hello Andy, I noticed this micro switch (https://www.digikey.be/en/products/detail/cts-electrocomponents/218-4LPSTJ/5223842 ) has a capacitance of 10 pF, I wonder if this will be in series will the transducer? if yes, the series equivalent would be around  10 pF?! and it can cause instability?

I have no idea where this microswitch is in the circuit but, if it says it has 10 pF capacitance it probably means the capacitance between terminals when open-circuit

@ Andy aka Hello Andy, I draw a schematic and added it to the end of of this post to be clear about the position of the micro switches in the circuit. Would you please share you idea now? (please consider in our circuit we will have 4 channels not two channels)

Unfortunately the data sheet gives no indication of the open-circuit switch capacitance across each individual switch. Are you still worried about cross-talk? If you are I suggest you don't modify this question any more and raise a new one and open it up to the whole floor. See my comment above to Tim Williams about the danger of extending questions. Your original question was about reflections and that has been put to bed @Andromeda

Reflection is a free-wave (or, at least transmission line) phenomena.  At 7MHz, the pins would have to be some 100s m long for reflection to apply -- at least in the most literal sense, where we could apply geometric optics.
At such low frequencies, and with respect to most circuit-scale components (mm to cm long), the LF equivalent of those structures -- stray inductance and capacitance -- suffices for analysis purposes.  So, shop accordingly -- off-capacitance is a common specification, or if the geometry is known, it can be calculated with rules of thumb (e.g. parallel-wire capacitance), or a quasi-static 2D or 3D field solver.
This greatly simplifies analysis, for example if you need some given isolation between channels, then you must design the layout, and choose switches/jumpers/etc., with such capacitance that, compared to source and/or load impedance, the isolation is met.  I can't show how to perform this calculation without an example system the component is embedded within, but suffice it to say, AC steady-state analysis will do the job.
